# MS access convert convert rows to columns

Tags: ms-access-2007, crosstab

I'm working on a database in MS Access 2007 for a flight simulator, and I need to pivot the data - that is, convert the rows to columns.

It's difficult to explain, so let me show what my problem is.

The data I have to start with looks like this:

```
Waypoint Lat            Lon    previous/next  minimim-alt   airwayName
00MKK   22.528056   -156.170961    BITTA          12         R464
00MKK   22.528056   -156.170961    CKH99          12         R464
03SML   25.61       30.635278      57SML          195        L321
03SML   25.61       30.635278      AST             85        W8
03SML   25.61       30.635278      KHG             85        W8
03SML   25.61       30.635278      KUNAK          195        L321

I need the data to look like this:

Waypoint  Lat      Lon        AirwayName Previous Next    AirwayName Previous Next 
03SML    25.61     30.635278  L321       57SML    KUNAK   W8         AST      KHG
00MKK    22.52805  -156.1709  R464       BITTA    CKH99   blank      blank    blank
```

For every airway the same waypoint has, I need a new column with the previous and next fields next to it. Each waypoint may have several airways associated with it(usually not more than 10). The order in which the previous and next entries appear is not especially important.

From what I've gathered, if this is even possible, this kind of operation can be done using multiple crosstab queries.

Any help is appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: I reckon you need VBA, not SQL.

Comment: I found a word to describe what this is. It's called denormalizing data. Now I need to figure out how to do that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I reckon you need VBA. You  can create a recordset ordered by Waypoint and just keep adding to a delimited string until the next waypoint. This way, you will end up with something that can be saved as a CSV. Alternatively, if it is a once off and there are not too many rows, you might consider importing the whole lot into Excel and doing the work there.